# ImageAreaSelect: preselect biggest thumbnail possible respecting aspectRatio

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, crop, aspect-ratio

This is how I first tried:

```
$('#thumbnail').imgAreaSelect({ 
    x1: 5,
    y1: 5,
    x2: $('#thumbnail').width(),
    y2: $('#thumbnail').width()*0.66,
    aspectRatio: '1:0.66'
});
```

But some of the cropped image stay off the overflow...

This seems to make a preselection for most of the image resolutions I tried...

```
var thwidth = $('#thumbnail').width();
var thheight = $('#thumbnail').height();
aspectRatio = 0.66;

$('#thumbnail').imgAreaSelect({ 
    x1: 5,
    y1: 5,
    x2: thwidth - 80,
    y2: (thwidth - 80) * aspectRatio,
    aspectRatio: '1:0.66'
});
```

But it won't select the maximum possible; plus it looks a bit dirty to me...

How can I select **the biggest** (centereded, if possible) width/height coordinates **that respects the aspect ratio**? (in this case: 1:0.66)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code

```
        var selWidth = 500;

        var photo = $('#photo'),
           photoWidth = parseInt($('#photo').width()),
           maxWidth = Math.min(selWidth, photoWidth)
           aspectRatio = 0.66,
           maxHeight = maxWidth * aspectRatio,
           yTop = parseInt(photo.height()) / 2 - maxHeight / 2;

        $('img#photo').imgAreaSelect({
           x1: photoWidth / 2 - maxWidth / 2,
           y1: yTop,
           x2: (photoWidth / 2 - maxWidth / 2) + maxWidth,
           y2: yTop + maxHeight
        });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cePZm/1/) This code creates a **centered** selection area **with given aspect ratio** and **max width**. If *max width* exceeds that of the image, it uses image's width as *max width*. Please note that it works with jquery 1.8.3 which I think is because of the imageareaselect plugin not being compatible with newest jquery verions (I'm not sure though).

---

### Update

I've improved the code to include the cases of *height overflwo* and *aspectRatio > 1*. I hope this works in all conditions :)

```
        var selWidth = 350;

        var photo = $('#photo'),
           photoWidth = parseInt($('#photo').width()),
           photoHeight = parseInt($('#photo').height()),
           maxWidth = Math.min(selWidth, photoWidth),
           aspectRatio = 0.66,
           maxHeight = maxWidth * aspectRatio;

        if (maxHeight > photoHeight) {
           maxHeight = photoHeight;
           maxWidth = maxHeight * ( 1 / aspectRatio);
        }

        var yTop = photoHeight / 2 - maxHeight / 2;

        $('img#photo').imgAreaSelect({
           x1: photoWidth / 2 - maxWidth / 2,
           y1: yTop,
           x2: (photoWidth / 2 - maxWidth / 2) + maxWidth,
           y2: yTop + maxHeight
        });
```

Comment: Upvote for the max width. Good call. :) Would this script work with an aspect ratio > 1? (e.g. portrait mode thumbs)

Comment: Hi there! thanks for your time! I am about to test.. what I don't understad why is var selWidth a constant (And wich width represents, at all)?

Comment: It is supposed to be a maximum size for the area to crop out of the image. If the image is way larger, it would just select the middle 500px portion.

Comment: `selWidth` defines selection area width. if you set `selWidth` too large, it'll just select the whole image's widht. If you don't want to set it manually, just do `maxWidth = photoWidth` where you find appropriate.

Comment: I see, I replaced it with my own biggest posible with. This works great! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I prepared this little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJAQp/).
It took me a little longer than Ejay, but I included a visual demonstration.

After calculating the position and width of the thumb, you could call it simple as that. (Using variable names from the fiddle)

```
$('#thumbnail').imgAreaSelect({ 
    x1: thumbX,
    y1: thumbY,
    x2: thumbX+thumbW,
    y2: thumbY+thumbH,
});
```