# ImageAreaSelec: It wont preview the pre-selection on init

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, methods, imageareaselect

this is how I am preselecting  (thanks to this question/answer [ImageAreaSelect: preselect biggest thumbnail possible respecting aspectRatio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990847/imageareaselect-preselect-biggest-thumbnail-posible-respecting-aspectratio))

```
var thwidth = $('#thumbnail').width();
    var thheight = $('#thumbnail').height();
    var aspectRatio = <?php echo $thumb_height/$thumb_width;?>;

var selWidth = 640;

var photo = $('#thumbnail'),
   photoWidth = parseInt($('#thumbnail').width()),
   maxWidth = Math.min(selWidth, photoWidth),
   maxHeight = maxWidth * aspectRatio,
   yTop = parseInt(photo.height()) / 2 - maxHeight / 2;



var thumbsel = $('#thumbnail').imgAreaSelect({ 
    x1: photoWidth / 2 - maxWidth / 2,
    y1: yTop,
    x2: (photoWidth / 2 - maxWidth / 2) + maxWidth,
    y2: yTop + maxHeight,
    aspectRatio: '1:<?php echo $thumb_height/$thumb_width;?>',
    onSelectStart: function(){
        $('#filters li').first().find('a').click();
    },
    onSelectChange: preview,
    onInit: preview,
    handles: true,
    resizable:true,
    show:true 
});
```

But the preview method it doesn't seem to be loaded on Init. User needs to re-select, resize or at least dragg current selection so it's previewed:

The preview method (taken from their site)

```
function preview(img, selection) {
    $('#filters li').first().find('a').click();
    var scaleX = <?php echo $thumb_width;?> / selection.width;
    var scaleY = <?php echo $thumb_height;?> / selection.height;

    $('#uploaded_file').css({
        width: Math.round(scaleX * <?php echo $current_large_image_width;?>) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(scaleY * <?php echo $current_large_image_height;?>) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px'
    });
    $('#x1').val(selection.x1);
    $('#y1').val(selection.y1);
    $('#x2').val(selection.x2);
    $('#y2').val(selection.y2);
    $('#w').val(selection.width);
    $('#h').val(selection.height);
}
```

I tried with this on the init function:

```
$('.imgareaselect-selection').mouseup();
```

But with no much success...

But I believe that the solution would be in re-producing the selection dragged or something similar?

-EDIT-

If you checkout this screenshot:

[image]

you can see that the preselection has been successfully done, but the prevew didn't..

If I just click/move the selection: then it's previewed

[image]

So the question would be:

How can I reproduce the selection changed? vía plugin methods or DOM events

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QyVy6/7/)

-EDIT2-

Well I came out with this solution, why not running preview function after the plugin init?

```
var my_options = {
        x1 : photoWidth / 2 - maxWidth / 2,
        y1 : yTop,
        width : (photoWidth / 2 - maxWidth / 2) + maxWidth - photoWidth / 2 - maxWidth / 2,
        height : yTop + maxHeight - yTop
}
preview('',my_options);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: It's a bit complex for me to provide a jsfiddle because I've implemented this only after an image is uploaded. I prepared a ugly one where you can see a bad selection done (allthoug the dragg indicators are not visible. I'm not so sure why), you can see that untill you dragg over the first image, the second one will not be updated. I would like to reproduce this, but I didn't see a method for it in the plugin docs... any thoughts? http://jsfiddle.net/QyVy6/7/

Comment: I see no problem on this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/QyVy6/11/)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your time, please check the screenshots I added to my question edit. For some reason the selection sqare is not visible in the jsfiddle I made

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand what the problem is. On the link I provided you, what I see is that it is successfully previewed, if I click it, it doesn't change, because it is already previewed on the right position.

Comment: Well... that's a bummer... In my server looks as in the screenshots...

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail)

Comment: I see no problems here (Chrome/Win7) on http://jsfiddle.net/QyVy6/11/. What browser are you using, @ToniMichelCaubet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track trying to construct the selection object manually, but I'd guess it didn't work because you didn't populate the x2, y2 fields. Here's a working example for the preview displaying on page load: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QyVy6/16/)

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div align="center">
        <img src="http://funcook.com/upload_pic_r/resize_1366627050.jpg" id="thumbnail" alt="Create Thumbnail" />
            <h2>Previsualiza el resultado</h2>

        <div id="uploaded_file_holder" style="border:1px #e5e5e5 solid; float:left; position:relative; left: 44px; overflow:hidden; width:640px; height:380px;">
            <img id="uploaded_file" src="http://funcook.com/upload_pic_r/resize_1366627050.jpg" style="position: relative;" alt="Thumbnail Preview" />
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="/picture_recipe.php" class="save_recipe_image" name="thumbnail">
            <input type="hidden" id="x1" value="" name="x1" />
            <input type="hidden" id="y1" value="" name="y1" />
            <input type="hidden" id="x2" value="" name="x2" />
            <input type="hidden" id="y2" value="" name="y2" />
            <input type="hidden" id="w" value="" name="w" />
            <input type="hidden" id="h" value="" name="h" />
            <input type="hidden" value="206" id="id_recipe" name="id_recipe" />
            <input type="text" value="" id="effectApplied" name="effectApplied" style="display: none;" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
function preview(img, selection) {
    $('#filters li').first().find('a').click();
    var scaleX = 640 / selection.width;
    var scaleY = 380 / selection.height;

    $('#uploaded_file').css({
        width: Math.round(scaleX * 550) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(scaleY * 412) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px'
    });

    $('#x1').val(selection.x1);
    $('#y1').val(selection.y1);
    $('#x2').val(selection.x2);
    $('#y2').val(selection.y2);
    $('#w').val(selection.width);
    $('#h').val(selection.height);
}

$(function () {
    var photo = $('#thumbnail'),
        selWidth = 640,
        aspectRatio = 0.59375,
        photoWidth = parseInt(photo.width()),
        maxWidth = Math.min(selWidth, photoWidth),
        maxHeight = Math.floor(maxWidth * aspectRatio),
        yTop = parseInt(photo.height()) / 2 - maxHeight / 2,
        selection = {
            x1: photoWidth / 2 - maxWidth / 2,
            y1: yTop,
            x2: (photoWidth / 2 - maxWidth / 2) + maxWidth,
            y2: yTop + maxHeight
        };

    selection.height = selection.y2 - selection.y1;
    selection.width = selection.x2 - selection.x1;

    var thumbsel = photo.imgAreaSelect({
        x1: selection.x1,
        y1: selection.y1,
        x2: selection.x2,
        y2: selection.y2,
        aspectRatio: '1:0.59375',
        onSelectStart: function () {
            $('#filters li').first().find('a').click();
        },
        onSelectChange: preview,
        onSelectEnd: preview,
        handles: true,
        resizable: true,
        show: true
    });

    preview(null, selection);
});
```